# Websocket sync two way connection

Tags: node.js, websocket

[image]

I am constrained to use the above data flow.

A node.js server receives a call to launch a command to a client connected to the node.js server by websocket.

The normal flow ends at the client after the browser websocket call an instruction on a javascript library.

```
Es.
REST CALL -> KillAllHumans
NODEJS -> pass KillAllHumans to websocket;
BROWSER -> onmessage -> javascript_library.killAllHumans;
```

A special method of REST ENDPOINT needs to return a value generated by the javascript library so the node.js has to remain pending until websocket client responds.

The question is: is it possible?
This is the simple websocket code on browser.

```
echo_service = new WebSocket(websocketUrl,"echo-protocol"); 
    echo_service.onmessage = function(event)
    {
       var result = javascript_library.manageAction(event.data);
       console.log("killAllHumansResults: "+result);
       return result;
    }
```

The return statement seems not working.

**EDITED:**

this is the body of the REST API that received the REST CALL.
wsServer is the websocket object class. Look at the result var. this is the response returned to the client that has invoked the REST CALL (using the callback function).

```
var result = this._wsServer.sendMessage(<ip_client>,<parameters>);
 console.log("rest return: "+result);
 callback(error, result);
 return;
```

For Websocket object im using this node project:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket

send message is a simple call `connection.send(message);`

The client receives the message correctly. The "killAllHumansResults" is correctly printed.
Unfortunally "rest return:" is undefined.

Its obviously that the print is launched before che remaining flow is completed.

Comment: What do you mean by not working ? Is the output improper or not matching your need?

Comment: Removed some adverbs and made statements more succinct. Cleaned up some of the spelling errors and inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found a workaround using sleep library (npm install sleep).

```
this._wsServer.sendMessage(<ip_client>,<parameters>);
 sleep.sleep(5);
 var result = this._wsServer.getReceivedMessage(<ip_client>);
 callback(error, result);
 return;
```

Five seconds are enough to allow client to send back the data stored in wsServer.